# Right bar at bottom of pages

Tags: css, sidebar, blog

On my blog the right bar is under that page located. I can not find out how to fix it. I tried it with 3 columns, then it the right bar goes to the left.

https://www.deli-discount.nl/dd_nl/deliblog

Comment: It is the width of the columns. The main content is 80%. The right sidebar is 25%. One of them needs to be smaller

Comment: Where can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your css and update this:

```
.col-main {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

.col-right {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It was asked where to change this. `margin-top` is a nice addition :)

Answer (score 1):

> It is the width of the columns. The main content is 80%. The right sidebar is 25%. One of them needs to be smaller – **jscar**

Please check your CSS in `skin/frontend/YOUR/THEME/css/styles.css(?)` , somewhere you'll find:

```
.col-main {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
```

and that:

```
.col-right {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Seems you've merged your CSS files, so adjust you're files and refresh "JavaScript/CSS cache" from backend.

Comment: Works, only strange thing, only with 3 columns and not wtih 2 columns and right bar. I have an other strange thing, in the account tab at the top, I have Manufacturers in it, but I have no idea to get it out. Any idea ?

Comment: @PeterVis What do you mean with "not with to colums and right bar"? What happens there? For different behavior for 2 or 3 columns, you can change or add to CSS `.col2-right-layout .col-main {...}` and `.col2-right-layout .col-right {...}` For the problem with the account tab you should ask another question.

Comment: I now found it is still not proberly set up at then search results page. Is there somewhere else where I not need to change something ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, on search results it shows the ancor but not the 3th column. And on the Manufacturers page the layout is messed up.

Comment: @PeterVis please ask this to who answered your question ... I asked you for feedback without getting any response. If i spent my time for helping, I expect some feedback if I ask back. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know how to use this site. Is not really logical. What I mean with the 2 column and right bar my template is a mess and with 3 column is working now. Even with adjusting what you told me.

Comment: @PeterVis Okay ... if I find some time in the evening I leave a comment.

Comment: Is really nice. It helps a lot.